# Compiled DiagonalMatrix

Tags: compile

The standard function DiagonalMatrix cannot be compiled, so I tried writing my own:

```
diagMat = Compile[{{vec, _Real, 1}},
                  Module[{size = Length[vec], matr},
                         matr = Table[0, {size}, {size}];
                         Do[matr[[i, i]] = vec[[i]], {i, size}];
                         matr]
];
```

While this function works, it does not compile. (I check this by doing Export["test.c",diagMat] , is there a simpler way to do this? )

It gives the error message:

> CCodeGenerate::wmreq: The expression Function[{vec,iCompile$67,matrCompile$68},Block[{i=iCompile$67,matr=matrCompile$68},{matr[[i,i]]=vec[[i]],i,matr}]] requires Mathematica to be evaluated.   The function will be generated but can be expected to fail with a nonzero error code when executed. >>

I'm not sure what's wrong here, as all the functions I use are compilable.

Thanks

Comment: Try changing `Table[0, (...)]` to `Table[0., (...)]`. Compiled functions don't like it when you mix reals with integers :).

Comment: Ah of course, thanks :)